# Chunked File Uploads have different file size/corrupt

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using jquery-file-upload and Python-Flask on the server side. Whenever I upload a large 100mb+ file, **the uploaded version is slightly larger than the original** and does not open (is corrupt). I have chunking enabled for large files at 10mb chunks, I've tried to set "disableImageResize" to "true" as well as tried single and multiple files and the result has been the same. Am I missing something in my code?

main.js

```
$(function () {
'use strict';
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'rs_upload',
    disableImageResize: true,
    sequentialUploads: true,
   // redirect: 'home',
    done: function (e, data) {
        console.log("uploaded: " + data.files[0].name)

    }
    , maxChunkSize: 10000000, // 10 MB,
}).bind('fileuploadstop', function (e, data) {
    if (data.loaded == data.total){window.location.replace("rs_create")}
});
```

views.py

```
@app.route("/rs_upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def rs_upload():
if request.method == 'POST':
    files = request.files['file']
    fs = files
    handle_file(fs)
    fullpath = session.get('finalpath')
    if 'Content-Range' in request.headers:
        # extract starting byte from Content-Range header string
        range_str = request.headers['Content-Range']
        start_bytes = int(range_str.split(' ')[1].split('-')[0])

        # append chunk to the file on disk, or create new
        with open(fullpath, 'a') as f:
            f.seek(start_bytes)
            f.write(fs.stream.read())

    else:
        # this is not a chunked request, so just save the whole file
        fs.save(fullpath)

    return jsonify({"name": fs.filename,
                    "size": os.path.getsize(fullpath),
                    "url": 'uploads/' + fs.filename,
                    "thumbnail_url": None,
                    "delete_url": None,
                    "delete_type": None,})

return render_template('remote_sensing/upload.html')
```

Comment: `disableImageResize` is basically for the middleware not to resize images (with imageMagik) so probably has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: difficult to debug without the file and the rest... but I'd look into `# extract starting byte from Content-Range header string
        range_str = request.headers['Content-Range']
        start_bytes = int(range_str.split(' ')[1].split('-')[0])` where you get your offset. Maybe that is not always coming in right.

Comment: also, you open the file with the flag `a`, did you try `ab` for appending in binary? because the content you get is likely binary unless it's text and you should check for encoding type etc...

Comment: Looks like it was simply the flag "a" instead of the "ab" binary flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if this is the issue, but would try

`with open(fullpath, 'ab') as f:`

to open & append to the file in binary mode.